# C# html table sort

Tags: c#, asp.net, html-table

I have a website developed using ASP.Net and C# that takes input from Active Directory and prints the data in an HTML table in the site. The code looks like this:

```
void SetupResults(SearchDataItems items)
    {

       HtmlTable t = new HtmlTable();
        HtmlTableRow r = new HtmlTableRow();
        HtmlTableCell c = new HtmlTableCell();




        c.VAlign = "center";
        c.Align = "middle";
        c.Width = "200px";
        c.InnerHtml = "User";
        r.Cells.Add(c);

        c = new HtmlTableCell();
        c.VAlign = "center";
        c.Align = "middle";
        c.Width = "180px";
        c.InnerHtml = "UserId";
        r.Cells.Add(c);

        c = new HtmlTableCell();
        c.VAlign = "center";
        c.Align = "middle";
        c.Width = "800px";
        c.InnerHtml = "Location";
        r.Cells.Add(c);

        c = new HtmlTableCell();
        c.VAlign = "center";
        c.Align = "middle";
        c.Width = "280px";
        c.InnerHtml = "Date Created";
        r.Cells.Add(c);

        c = new HtmlTableCell();
        r.Cells.Add(c);

        r.Style.Add("background-color", "SteelBlue");
        r.Style.Add("color", "white");
        r.Style.Add("font-size", "medium");

        tblItems.Rows.Add(r);





        for (int i = 0; i < items.ListItem.Count; i++)
        {

            r = new HtmlTableRow();

            if (i % 2 == 1)
                r.BgColor = "#A9D0F5";

            c = new HtmlTableCell();

            LinkButton lnk = null;

            c.VAlign = "Top";
            c.Align = "Left";
            c.Width = "200px";
            c.InnerHtml = items.ListItem[i].Name;
            r.Cells.Add(c);

            c = new HtmlTableCell();
            c.VAlign = "Top";
            c.Align = "Left";
            c.Width = "180px";
            c.InnerHtml = items.ListItem[i].UserID;
            r.Cells.Add(c);

            c = new HtmlTableCell();
            c.VAlign = "Top";
            c.Align = "Left";
            c.Width = "800px";
            c.InnerHtml = StripOUGarbage(items.ListItem[i].OU);
            r.Cells.Add(c);

            c = new HtmlTableCell();
            c.VAlign = "Top";
            c.Align = "Left";
            c.Width = "280px";
            c.InnerHtml = items.ListItem[i].AccountCreateDate.ToString();
            r.Cells.Add(c);

            c = new HtmlTableCell();
            c.VAlign = "Top";
            c.Align = "Left";
            lnk = new LinkButton();
            lnk.Text = "Edit";
            lnk.ToolTip = "Edit " + items.ListItem[i].Name;
            lnk.ID = i.ToString() + "_" + items.ListItem[i].Name;
            lnk.Click += lnk_Click;
            lnk.OnClientClick = "ShowProgress();";
            c.Controls.Add(lnk);
            r.Cells.Add(c);


            tblItems.Rows.Add(r);
        }

        //if (items.ListItem.Count > 0)
        //{
        //    divTable.Controls.Add(t);
        //}

    }
```

It runs and returns the info fine, but the sorting is off. It mostly returns by User create date (although there appear to be some inconsistencies there too). I would prefer to have it return alphabetically by user name, is there a way to auto sort these columns, or be able to have a user sort them by clicking the column headers would be nice too.

Any input would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: There are too many potential answers to this question. Do you want to sort the data before you build the table or do you actually want a table where you can click a header to sort?

Comment: Is there a reason you don't sort the results as part of your query that gets the data?

Comment: maybe it needs to be configurable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To sort by name at the server level (effectively your default sort), just add this line before your `for` loop building the table.

```
var sortedItems = items.ListItem.OrderBy(m => m.Name).ToList();
```

Then you update all your values to use sortedItems (including the condition of your `for` loop). For example:

```
c.InnerHtml = sortedItems[i].Name;
```

As for sorting your table at the client level, I'd recommend opening a new question on that once you've checked out a few options and start going down a specific path. With Angular, JQuery plugins and more, there are too many other options to even mention.

**UPDATE TO SHOW SAMPLE CODE**

You would do the updates within your loop. Here's your code with the changes.

```
        var sortedItems = sortedItems.OrderBy(m => m.Name).ToList();
        for (int i = 0; i < sortedItems.Count; i++)
        {

            r = new HtmlTableRow();

            if (i % 2 == 1)
                r.BgColor = "#A9D0F5";

            c = new HtmlTableCell();

            LinkButton lnk = null;

            c.VAlign = "Top";
            c.Align = "Left";
            c.Width = "200px";
            c.InnerHtml = sortedItems[i].Name;
            r.Cells.Add(c);

            c = new HtmlTableCell();
            c.VAlign = "Top";
            c.Align = "Left";
            c.Width = "180px";
            c.InnerHtml = sortedItems[i].UserID;
            r.Cells.Add(c);

            c = new HtmlTableCell();
            c.VAlign = "Top";
            c.Align = "Left";
            c.Width = "800px";
            c.InnerHtml = StripOUGarbage(sortedItems[i].OU);
            r.Cells.Add(c);

            c = new HtmlTableCell();
            c.VAlign = "Top";
            c.Align = "Left";
            c.Width = "280px";
            c.InnerHtml = sortedItems[i].AccountCreateDate.ToString();
            r.Cells.Add(c);

            c = new HtmlTableCell();
            c.VAlign = "Top";
            c.Align = "Left";
            lnk = new LinkButton();
            lnk.Text = "Edit";
            lnk.ToolTip = "Edit " + sortedItems[i].Name;
            lnk.ID = i.ToString() + "_" + sortedItems[i].Name;
            lnk.Click += lnk_Click;
            lnk.OnClientClick = "ShowProgress();";
            c.Controls.Add(lnk);
            r.Cells.Add(c);


            tblItems.Rows.Add(r);
        }
```

Comment: Sorry for the newbness, but where do I add the: c.InnerHtml = sortedItems[i].Name; line? I would imagine it's at the end of the for loop, but it give a cannot apply indexing error.

Comment: No problem, just did a replace with your code to show what it'd look like.

Comment: Awesome, that did the trick. Make sense now that I see it. Appreciate the help and will give you a point once I hit 15 rep.